# Images corruption in VisualC++ WinForms project

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio, visual-c++

In several WinForms solutions we're getting an annoying bug: images used in buttons or stored in `ImageList` controls keep losing quality, after an unpredictable number of rebuild.

Here is an example:

- Correct image:
  [image]
- Corrupted image:
  [image]

All images are stored in form's resx files and are assigned using Designer Mode.
We encountered this bug on different computers and since Visual Studio 2008, through Visual Studio 2010 and is still present in Visual Studio 2013.

Actually, as workaround, we replace corrupted images, with the initial uncorrupted images, assigning again them in the Designer Mode.

Is it a known issue of Visual Studio? Is there any way to definitively fix it without replacing images?